# How to grep for a particular pattern within another pattern

Tags: shell, unix, awk, grep

I'm trying to write a shell script where i have a file with a list of file names in it. Now i want to grep for a pattern if it exists within that file. Here is the example.

File name : Check.txt

```
YYY28590301456967003510KKKxxxxxxxxxxxx_001_00051_20140616.dat
YYY5125741025CCCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_002_05977_20140616.dat
```

Now i want to grep for this pattern "28590301456967003510KKKxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_001_00051.dat" within the file Check.txt. Please note that i'm only concerned about the pattern  **28590301456967003510KKK**  and the sequence **00051** for that particular file pattern. And since i'll have multiple files to check for how to loop through this.?. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Any time you write a loop in shell to parse a text file you have the wrong approach. This sounds like you just need a simple `grep` command (See @AvinashRaj's answer) but if there's more to your requirements than you've told us so far then you'd use `awk`. In either case you would not write a shell loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this command inside the directory which contains all the files in which you are trying to search for,

```
grep '28590301456967003510KKK.*00051' *.txt
```

Example:

```
$ cat foo.txt
YYY28590301456967003510KKKxxxxxxxxxxxx_001_00051_20140616.dat
YYY5125741025CCCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_002_05977_20140616.dat

$ cat bar.txt
YYY28590301456967003510KKKxxxxxxxxxxxx_001_00051_20140616.dat
YYY5125741025CCCxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_002_05977_20140616.dat
foo
bar

$ grep '28590301456967003510KKK.*00051' *.txt
foo.txt:YYY28590301456967003510KKKxxxxxxxxxxxx_001_00051_20140616.dat
bar.txt:YYY28590301456967003510KKKxxxxxxxxxxxx_001_00051_20140616.dat
```

If the pattern you want to search inside the files which are present inside the subdirectories, you could try this command

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 -type f -name "*.txt" | xargs grep '28590301456967003510KKK.*00051'
./foo.txt:YYY28590301456967003510KKKxxxxxxxxxxxx_001_00051_20140616.dat
./foo-bar/aa.txt:YYY28590301456967003510KKKxxxxxxxxxxxx_001_00051_20140616.dat
```

It finds the files along with it's path and also the texts which matches the pattern.

**OR**

you could use grep also to search on files inside subdirectories,

```
$ grep -R --include="*.txt" '28590301456967003510KKK.*00051' .
./aa1.txt:YYY28590301456967003510KKKxxxxxxxxxxxx_001_00051_20140616.dat
./foo-bar/ram.txt:YYY28590301456967003510KKKxxxxxxxxxxxx_001_00051_20140616.dat
```

`-R` -> Recursive

`--include="*.txt"` -> only .txt files

`'28590301456967003510KKK.*00051'`  -> pattern

`.` -> current directory.(from the directory grep operation is going to takeplace).

Comment: Hi, if its a loop actually then what should i do.? Indivudually it's fine :)

Comment: you mean if the files are inside subdirectories?

Comment: Hi, i think there's a little bit confusion here. All my file names will be within a particular file and i want to search pattern only within that particular file and not within any directories.

Comment: then try `grep '28590301456967003510KKK.*00051' Check.txt`

Comment: +1 for the simple grep command but no-one should ever use `grep -R` to find files. The UNIX command to find files is `find` (there is a clue in the name!).